# python list of dicts remove items with empty lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

with a list `l` like below

```
l = [{'x': 2}, {'y': [], 'z': 'hello'}, {'a': []}]
```

need to eject the elements with an empty list as the value.

expected output

```
[{'x': 2}, {z: 'hello'}]
```

Was trying to achieve this with list comprehension, need help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work for your data:

```
>>> [d for d in ({k: v for k, v in d_.items() if v} for d_ in l) if d]
[{'x': 2}, {'z': 'hello'}]
```

The inner dict comprehension filters out those key-value pairs from the dicts with empty list values, the outer comprehension filters empty dicts.

Comment: What about `[{'x': 0}, {'z': ''}]` ?

Comment: A possible approach `[d for d in ({k: v for k, v in d_.items() if v or isinstance(v, str)} for d_ in l) if d]` @Błotosmętek

Comment: I like @Ch3steR's answer more - it is cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.

```
list(filter(None,({k:v for k,v in d.items() if v!=[]} for d in l)))
#[{'x': 2}, {'z': 'hello'}]
```

Comment: `if v` will filter out `0` or `""`, not just `[]`.

Comment: @Błotosmętek agreed. OP wanted to only replace empty lists. editing it away.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to: a) Use a simple loop to remove empty entries and b) filter the final list:

```
l = [{'x': 2}, {'y': [], 'z': 'hello'}, {'a': []}]

for i,d in enumerate(l):
    l[i]={k:v for k,v in d.items() if v!=[]}
l=list(filter(None, l))  

>>> l
[{'x': 2}, {'z': 'hello'}]
```

The advantage here (over a comprehension) is the list is edited in place vs copied.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similar to existing responses, but uses a one-iteration list comprehension, with `if` to filter out the empty items.

```py
def remove_empty(input_list):
    return [dict((k, v) for k, v in d.items() if v != [])
            for d in input_list
            if not (len(d) == 1 and list(d.values()) == [[]])]

remove_empty(l)
```

output:

```
[{'x': 2}, {'z': 'hello'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :

```
l = [{'x': 2}, {'y': [], 'z': 'hello'}, {'a': [],'b':'','c':0}]
print([ { k:v for k,v in ll.items() if v != [] } for ll in l ]);
```